# Вывод результата двумя столбцами

Tags: python, циклы

Имеем два цикла:

```
for a1 in r1:
    print a1

for a2 in r2:
    print a2
```

Вопрос, как вывести два столбца в один результат, например:

```
данные a1 | данные а2
данные a1 | данные а2
данные a1 | данные а2
```

Answer (score 5):

Для этого существует стандартная функция [zip](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for t in zip(r1, r2):
    print t[0], t[1]
```

Answer (score 4):

Если r1 и r2 - cписки или кортежи, то

```
for a in zip(r1, r2):  
    print a[0], a[1]
```

Comment: Круто, код точно такой же, как и в моем ответе =)
Кстати, аргументы не обязательно должны быть списками или кортежами, а могут быть любыми итерируемыми объектами.

Answer (score 2):

```
for a, b in izip(A, B):  
    print a, b
```

Вот такой вариант будет лучше.

Answer (score 0):

Чтобы не писать `a[0], a[1]` можно сделать так:

```
for a in zip(a1, a2):
    print(*a)
```

Comment: Ох, какую древность подняли. В те времена по дефолту подразумевался Python2, и с print в Python2 такая штука не сработает. Не уверен, что имеет смысл давать ответы на такие древние вопросы.

Comment: По работе приходится смотреть кое-какие древние ответы, решила почему бы не актуализировать.